# How to make external REST API calls inside Google Cloud Functions - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am new to NodeJs and Google Cloud Functions and I am working on a collaborative project where we use cloud functions to process transaction information which is then sent to our custom backend(written in Go Lang) that triggers a validation process for users to approve a transaction, which then updates documents in Firestore database.

Here is my cloud function:

```
exports.processDepositTransactions = functions.firestore.document('TransactionRequests/{phone}/All/{docID}').onCreate(async(snap, context)=> {
  var data = snap.data()
  const transactionId = generateTransactionId()
if(data.transactionType === "deposit"){
    console.log('Processing deposit transactions')
    var payload = {
            // my payload here
      }

 //Post to data to endpoint for processing  
// API Call
      await fetch(
        "https://myendpoint.com/deposit",
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify(payload),
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        }
      ).then((resp)=> {
        if(resp.status >= 200 && resp.status <= 300){
          admin.firestore().collection("Deposit").add({
            amount: data.amount,
            transactionId: transactionId,
            by: data.by,
            docId: snap.id,
            status: "init",
            sentAt: new Date(),
          });
        return Promise.resolve(resp.json())
        }
      }).then((data)=> {
        console.log(data)

      })
```

**My problem:**

Whenever I deploy my functions with the API call, The function keeps creating similar documents in Deposit Collection non-stop, spamming our Firestore collection and not actually hitting our end point in the custom backend. I tried commenting the API call code and the document is added fine. So the problem seems to originate from the API call code. I tried some other code on making API calls in NodeJS but all end with the sam problem

**My Questions:**

- How can we actually hit our end point without spamming our collection?
- I am using the proper way to make API Calls in NodeJs?
- Is there another way to hit external end points within Google Cloud Functions?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want multiple entry point in your cloud functions? Like a webserver?

Comment: Not really...I'm just trying to find a way to make an API call to our backend from our cloud functions after a certain document is created in a collection

Comment: have a look to the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) is it helpful?

Comment: Thank you for the reference @DivyaniYadav. I went through the documentation and I found out it explains calling functions through HTTP. But our case requires us to make HTTP request to our custom backend from our cloud functions.

Comment: can you see this [link](https://maxkatz.net/2018/07/20/how-to-invoke-an-external-rest-api-from-a-cloud-function/) is it helpful?